# Hibernate Criteria Date comparison

Tags: hibernate, date, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to fetch data according to condition that attribute date1 is 17 minutes later than attribute date2. I can write the code to select based on condition date1 is later than date2 by using:

```
Restrictions.gtProperty("date1", "date2")
```

But I didn't find a good way to add the 17 minutes condition to it. HQL solution is not ideal but is also acceptable if someone knows how to do that.

Comment: I got a work around to just load data based on condition date1 > date2, then filter in memory using Java. Since the interval is only 17 minutes, it should not load too much unnecessary data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `sqlRestriction`, which would allow you to directly embed SQL in your `Criteria` query.  You could then use platform-specific SQL to do the comparison. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-narrowing